# Label text remains unchanged

Tags: vb.net

So I'm deliberately trying to make a Download ETA Calculator using Visual Basic 2013 Ultimate.. but after 3 hours of work, I tried running it but it won't show the final result (The Estimated Time). I am also asking you how to convert the result into Time format..
here is the code

```
Public Class Form1

Private Property z As Object

Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub LinkLabel1_LinkClicked(sender As Object, e As 
            LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs) Handles LinkLabel1.LinkClicked
    Process.Start("www.speedtest.net")
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
                          Handles Button1.Click
    Dim x, y, z, a As Integer
    Dim sum

    x = TextBox1.Text
    y = TextBox2.Text
    sum = Label1

    If RadioButton1.Checked = True And RadioButton3.Checked = True Then
        z = x / 1024 / y
        a = z / 60
        sum = a / 60
    End If

    If RadioButton1.Checked = True And RadioButton4.Checked = True Then
        z = x / 1024 / y
        a = z / 60 * 1024
        sum = a / 60
    End If
    If RadioButton2.Checked = True And RadioButton3.Checked = True Then
        z = x / 1048576 / y
        a = z / 60
        sum = a / 60
    End If
    If RadioButton2.Checked = True And RadioButton4.Checked = True Then
        z = x / 1048576 / y
        a = z / 60 * 1024
        sum = a / 60
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
                                        Handles                                                  
                                        RadioButton1.CheckedChanged

End Sub
End Class
```

Error 2
http://tny.cz/7b5711f7

Error 3
http://tny.cz/09bf1f96

Comment: What's the exaxt error?

Comment: Can you provide sample values for TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text and Label1?

Comment: @ChristianSauer there is no error.. the thing is that there is answer in label1 after typing the data...

Comment: @Ninjapig Textbox1 is the File Size i.e. 2 GB, Textbox2 is the internet speed i.e 1Mb/s and the label is the time taken i.e 1:56:37

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim sum
sum = Label1
```

Presumably Label1 is a label control so you're setting a variable to be equal to the label control.

Later on, you're trying to set this variable of type label control to a decimal

```
sum = a / 60
```

I would say you want probably want to replace all your

```
sum = a / 60
```

with something like

```
label1.Text = New TimeSpan(a / 60, 0, 0).ToString()
```

and forget about variable sum all together

Comment: It would be good design practice to place all the logic in a separate method (even project) that returns a result, whereas setting Label1.Text as you've described ties the presentation to the business logic.

Comment: Now my answer is always 0

Comment: @Ninjapig of course you are right here, but i'm only trying to fix the problem he's having, not rewrite his application for him :P

Comment: @user3454677 well, we've solved the problem of why your label's text value wasn't being set. You'll have to debug your application to work out why your variable a is getting set to 0

Comment: I've also asked you that how to set the label1 to be displayed in the form of hh:mm:ss

Comment: @user3454677 are you currently calculating time in seconds, minutes or hours?

Comment: actually i'm just calculating raw like 2.23555557 will be 2.23 hours..
I'm trying to follow methods by [link](http://www.download-time.com)

Comment: so, you're calculating it in hours? See updated answer

Comment: After updating my project with the code you have given.. it shows the error in the updated question.

Comment: No errors now.. but The result I get has two zeros extra 
i.e 29.17:00:00 Hours
EDIT: Also How Can I make it work as a clock
i.e. if 6 hours 60 minutes how can I turn the hour to 7?

Comment: it should do that automatically

Comment: Wait.. It turns to 7 after its 6.. but if I put 1 GB as Size and 1 Mb/s as speed, then th result is
5.17:00:00 Hours

Comment: i think you'll find you have other errors in your program and the timespan is 5 days, 17 hours, 0 minutes, 0 seconds

Comment: this is probably worthy of a new question now if you're unable to find the problem